# added code slows down processing time significantly

Tags: performance, if-statement

I worked this code out stitching elements together.  It takes worksheets from a workbook, saves them as individual workbooks in a new folder then emails them to the PMs for their action.  I wrote it blindly not knowing how the workbook was structured.  Then I found out the workbook (it's a restricted access file), has the first 4 worksheets that I need to ignore.  I added another if loop to ignore worksheets that contain the string "IGNORE" in cell A2.  It was working so fast before I added this if statement now it seems to take a lot longer.   I fear it will be unreasonably slow on the workbook where I am going to implement it on (20 worksheets). I am going to watch it as it process in debug mode I guess, but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()
'TMP June 5, 2018 Export and save worksheets as new Workbook in a new folder
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
'TMP June 5, 2018 added following dims for auto email generator submodule
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
Dim eAdd As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
      xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        Select Case xWb.FileFormat
            Case 51:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56:
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
  Set eAdd = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
  If eAdd <> "IGNORE" Then
  xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        'TMP June 5,2018 Added submodule to create and show the Outlook mail item
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set eAdd = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    With oMail
        'selects the to from A1
        .to = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        'Sets the subject
        .Subject = "Your hammer sheet is attached"
        'Creates the body of the email
        .body = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Here is your hammer sheet to fill out and send back within 2 days" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thanks a lot," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Mounir Samara"
        .Attachments.Add xFile
        .Display
    End With
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
 End If ''IGNORE' if loop
Next
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Zev.  I am thinking that the slow processing is/was a function of running it at home as opposed to the office network after I made changes (on a test/dummy workbook).  It is running fairly well now for some reason.  I did use eAdd for two different purposes, which is probably bad programming or is it ultra-efficient? I will update this after I implement tomorrow at work on the real sheet.

Comment: Update:  an issue has occurred when I implemented it on the real workbook.  I get a break error on this line: Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

Comment: This does not give me an error when I run it on my computer.  ON his computer the workbook is stored on a restricted drive.  I tried copying the workbook to his unrestricted desktop and the same error occurred.  He has rights to both so I don't know why it would have an issue.  I used the immediate window and debug.print xFile to show the path of the file attempting to be saved:

Comment: Path when on restricted drive:J:\HAMMER\THE HAMMER.xlsm 2018-06-06 11-49-53\Fred.xlsx
Path when on his desktop:C:\Users\mounirsamara\Desktop\Weekly Hammer Sent\THE HAMMER.xlsm 2018-06-06 11-48-31\Fred.xlsx 
both of these result in the error, however work on my computer with this path:I:\Tom Park's Shared Documents\Hammer Macro\Test for validation, file split, save and email.macro.xlsm 2018-06-06 12-04-40\Sheet1.xlsx

Comment: They all look like valid paths and file names, so I am at a loss as to why it does not work on his PC!  Can anyone think of anything that could be causing this error?